# Why does Boq lie to Nessarose?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz, wicked

He had the perfect out, she knew that he had asked her out of pity.

Lyrics:

> [Boq]
>       Uh, Nessa. 
>       I've got something to confess, a
>       Reason why, well- 
>       Why I asked you here tonight 
>       Now I know it isn't fair...
>
> [Nessa]
>       Oh, Boq. I know why.
>
> [Boq]
>       You do?
>
> [Nessa]
>       It's because I'm in this chair 
>       And you felt sorry for me 
>       Well isn't that right?
>
> [Boq]
>       No! no! It's because..uh..because...
>       Because you are so beautiful...

I have only seen the play once and it seemed like Glenda was near so Boq was trying to impress her?

Answer (score 4):

**He lies to spare her feelings**:

Boq initially felt nothing at all for Nessa; he took her to the dance simply because Galinda suggested it.

Toward the end of the dance, Boq feels a little bad about his motivations, and was going to confess, but before he can, Nessarose interrupts, pathetically suggesting that Boq only asked her out due to pity.

Since Boq was about to confess to something even more humiliating for Nessa than that (to be moved by pity for Nessa would mean that Boq was thinking about Nessa at least a little. It's far worse for him to have taken Nessa to the dance only because Galinda had asked him to), Boq is moved to actual pity for Nessa - so he lies to make her feel better.

Answer (score 3):

In the stage version, Boq is watching Glinda and Fiyero dancing and flirting but they've only got eyes for each other and are pretty much ignoring Boq and Nessa.

After having watched the love of his life getting fondled on the dancefloor, Boq is on the verge of explaining to Nessa that the only reason he got close to her was in order to be near Glinda when he seems to have a change of heart. She accuses him of feeling sorry for her and she's dead right. He flat out lies to her that the reason he's so upset (and needing to confess) is because she's just so damn beautiful.

Their entire relationship is then based on this lie. Nessarose ultimately strips the Munchkins of their rights in an attempt to prevent Boq from leaving her.

> **Boq:** *I'm talking about my life. The little that's left of it. I'm not free to leave Munchkinland, none of us are. Ever since she took
>   power, she's been stripping the Munchkins of our rights... and we
>   didn't have that many to begin with! And do you know why?*
>
> Nessarose Reveals Herself In The Chair.
>
> **Nessarose:** **To keep you here, with me**. *But none of that matters anymore. Look.*